# Post web request to xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json

I have a vendor that has supplied me with info I need to code in order to receive information from them. I need to send a POST request out to a URL ending in .xml. The documentation gives a JSON format and returns a response in XML. I'm a C# programmer and am not familiar with this yet. What type of request is this and how can I find an example on how to do it? I'm simply unsure of what to search for. If I run this code in JSON in the .aspx file, are there any security risks that the user will be able to see code by doing a view source?

Comment: Ask the vendor for more information on what you need to do. Without any additional detail, this would be a very hard question to answer.

Comment: You (usually) don't _send_ Post requests with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Use WebClient to download it.

```
string xml = "";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
   xml  = client.DownLoadString("yourURL");   
}
// process the XML
```

I'm not sure what the JSON angle is, since the URI is ending in XML.
Inspect the string and see what you've got.

Comment: Thank you Henk, this is very helpful. I need to send parameter values, what else needs to be included?

Comment: WebClient takes a full URI, inc params. I would give it a run.